# Unusual QGI3S "Exception: Unkowns"

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, distance-matrix

I'm trying to process some OSM data extracted via Osmium. I've managed to process some of my smaller datasets, but as I've begun working on the bigger ones, I'm receiving some odd errors. Specifically, I've tried to batch-process SUMLINELENGTHS and to create an OD Matrix using QNEAT3. Oddly enough, the sumlinelengths tool works on individual layers, just not when applied as a batch.

Batch SUMLINELENGTHS Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\SumLines.py", line 119, in processAlgorithm
QgsFeatureRequest().setSubsetOfAttributes([]).setDestinationCrs(poly_source.sourceCrs(), context.transformContext())), feedback)
Exception: unknown
```

OD Matrix error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/dicki/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\OdMatrixFromPointsAsLines.py", line 207, in processAlgorithm
net = Qneat3Network(network, points, strategy, directionFieldName, forwardValue, backwardValue, bothValue, defaultDirection, analysisCrs, speedFieldName, defaultSpeed, tolerance, feedback)
File "C:/Users/dicki/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Framework.py", line 130, in __init__
self.list_tiedPoints = self.director.makeGraph(self.builder, self.list_input_points, self.feedback)
Exception: unknown

Execution failed after 53.70 seconds
```

Looking at my data, I see nothing about this set that should make it any different than the other sets which were processed successfully. I've never run into errors that looked like this before. I'm not even sure if these two error sets are related, and the unhelpful `exception: unknown` tag doesn't help me pry them apart. Any advice?